# Android - main app button text question

Tags: android, text, button

I'm very new to Android development and not sure yet how to solve this issue...

Is there a way to have the app launch button text set as a certain string, but the app text bar (horizontal bar accross the top of the app) set as something different?

For example, say my app button is labeled "MyApp".  Right now, the bar across the top also is labeled "MyApp".  I'd like it so the bar across the top is labeled "MyApp Testing".

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

These titles are in the manifest file. There is one title on the application node and another title on the activity node. In this example app_name will be shown as the icon text, and win_name at the top of the window:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".TestWin"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/win_name">
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. That is exaclty what I did, but for the life of me I can't get it to work quite right...

Comment: If I remove android:label="@string/win_name" , then the icon text is whatever I set the app_name to. But if I leave android:label="@string/win_name" in, then the icon text uses the win_name.

Comment: Actually.. this was easier than I made it out to be... I just set the this.setTitle("window title");